# Use of group by in Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this following piece of line when executed, gives me this error. How would I use exists here for the filter line 'next_NotedID' ? Thanks in Advance

```
 Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
    Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

this is my where clause

```
 where (Name = 'File Review' and next_Name = 'File Review')
                                                 and   (TYPECODE ='1200005' and next_Typecode = '1200005')
                                                 and   ((HEADLINE like '%Follow up letter%')
                                                        and (next_Headline like '%Follow up letter%'))
                                                  and next_NotedID <>  (SELECT  ParentRef, max(NoteID)from Stg.IG_Note group by PARENTREF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `subquery` as *correlated* :

```
. . .
and next_NotedID <> (SELECT max(nt.NoteID) 
                     from Stg.IG_Note nt 
                     where nt.PARENTREF = outerqueryalise.ParentRef
                     );
```

If you are comparing with `next_NotedID` with inner query `max(NoteID)` then you can directly express it as

```
and next_NotedID <> (select max(nt.NoteID) from Stg.IG_Note nt);
```

Comment: I need to compare  next_NotedID with inner query max(NoteID) per ParentRef

Comment: @BuddyCool. . . The preceding query is `correlated subquery` which should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
and next_NotedID <>  (SELECT  ParentRef, max(NoteID)from Stg.IG_Note group by PARENTREF)
```

to:

```
and next_NotedID <>  (SELECT  max(NoteID)from Stg.IG_Note group by PARENTREF)
```

You can not select more then 1 field in a sub select when using <>.  If this returns more then one possible value you would need to change it to NOT IN instead of <>

Comment: I'm actually looking the max(NoteID) per ParenRef number. SO , I would need that